# Replace line in files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

How to replace the line in the file that begins with the text `aaa` I do not know where the line is.

files.txt:

```
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = (aa,bb,cc)
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
```

Replace:

```
aaa = (aa,bb,cc)
```

For:

```
aaa = (dd,ee,ff)
```

Comment: I would probably use `sed` but it depends on how you want to change the line.  Do you need values from the old line to form the new line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to do a substitution with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^aaa = (aa,bb,cc)$/aaa = (dd,ee,ff)/' file
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = (dd,ee,ff)
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
```

The characters `^` and `$` match the start and the end of the line respectively in regexp meaning the substitution will only occur for whole line matches.

Once you are happy with the changes use the `-i` options to save back to the file.

```
$  sed -i 's/^aaa = (aa,bb,cc)$/aaa = (dd,ee,ff)/' file
```

**Edit:**

```
$ cat file
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = foo
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = bar

$ sed 's/^aaa = .*/aaa = (dd,ee,ff)/' file
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = (dd,ee,ff)
aaa = (dd,ee,ff)
sadasd_dsada = (aa,bb,cc)
aaa = (dd,ee,ff)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know what is behind the sign "=" :-(

Comment: That's no problem, see the edit.